# how to resolve this error in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have an error,my application spring boot don't run and the problème is:Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-17T00:15:33.920+01:00 ERROR 14000 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1173) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
at com.example.ma_banque.MaBanqueApplication.main(MaBanqueApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.createBasicBinder(PropertyBinder.java:1169) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindBasic(PropertyBinder.java:1071) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindProperty(PropertyBinder.java:890) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.buildProperty(PropertyBinder.java:788) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.processElementAnnotations(PropertyBinder.java:709) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(EntityBinder.java:977) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]

how to resolve it,give me a solution

Comment: Please add folder structure of your project and JpaConfiguration (if you have any) to the question.